# Using Dual Wielding, you can do two weapon fighting with a two handed weapon held in one hand.And can the other hand be a weapon that you just drawup?

Tags: dnd-5e, two-weapon-fighting

For example, in one turn, there is a Fighter that has Dual Wielding and uses Attack Action on the greatsword that was previously held.  He then chose to release the one hand holding the greatsword and used Interact with object to take out the longsword. Could he still do Two Weapon Fighting?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "do Two Weapon fighting" in this context? Make an offhand attack on the same turn with the longsword he just drew?

Comment: it seems that after using the attack action and doing the free action of removing the two hands holding the greatsword, leaving only one hand.  Then use interaction to pick up a longsword and attack with bonus action in one turn.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take a look at the [tour] and at the [help] for any guidance in posting on this site! Happy gaming!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### In order use the Two-weapon fighting Bonus Action you must already have both weapons in hand.

This is confirmed by the [Sage Advice Compendium](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/sac/sage-advice-compendium#SA263), that clarifies this very exact case:

> **Can I make an attack with one weapon, then draw a second weapon with my other hand and qualify to use two-weapon fighting?**
>
> To use the two-weapon fighting bonus action (PH), you must have both weapons in hand when you make the first attack. If you’re instead fighting with two or more weapons as part of the Extra Attack feature, the rule for the two-weapon fighting bonus action doesn’t apply. The rule for that bonus action applies only to itself, not to any other use of two or more weapons in the game.

The [Dual Wielder](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/dual-wielder) feat plays no role.

#### Dual Wielder feat does not allow to *use* a two handed weapon with just one hand.

The benefits are the following:

> - You gain a +1 bonus to AC while you are wielding a separate melee weapon in each hand.
> - You can use two-weapon fighting even when the one-handed melee weapons you are wielding aren't light.
> - You can draw or stow two one-handed weapons when you would normally be able to draw or stow only one.

Comment: Also in previous versions of the game this is also true, you needed to extent a full round action to make attacks with both weapons AND both weapons MUST be drawn before starting the attack.